# How to force ingress-nginx to redirect to HTTP only

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubectl, nginx-ingress

my ingress-nginx redirects the requests to HTTPS by default. I want to use HTTP. how can I do that?
this is my YAML file :

'''

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: mosi.ir
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: posts-srv
                port:
                  number: 3020
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
```

'''

Comment: Try setting annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.